# JSON decode issue

Tags: java, python, json, jackson, avro

I'm trying to decode JSON output of a Java program (jackson) and having some issues.
The cause of the problem is the following snippet:

```
{
    "description": "... lives\uMOVE™ OFFERS ",
}
```

Which causes `ValueError: Invalid \uXXXX escape`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: The output is from an Avro file, the Avro package uses jackson to emit records as JSON. 
EDIT2: After poking about in the source files, it might be the case that the JSON is constructed manually (sorry jackson).

Comment: how you are getting the output? did you try to encode it into utf-8 ?

Comment: I'm reading the output from Python (running java as sub process and reading it's stdout). I tried to use a utf-8 OutputStreamWriter, but it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Avro versions < 1.6.0.  See [AVRO-851](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-851) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

What's the original string supposed to look like? `\uXXXX` is a unicode escape sequence, so it's interpreting \uMOVE as a single character, but it's not a valid unicode value.  JSON is always assumed to be unicode, so you'll likely need to fix the string in the originating app

Comment: The originating app is the Avro packages (the toString method of the record). So I can't fix it at this level (other than writing my own JSON encoder for records).

Comment: Is the description text coming from you or the package? If the former, what's it supposed to look like?

Comment: It's coming from an Avro file.

Comment: Did you create theAvro file? In other words, what should the string look like encoding aside?

Comment: I have no control on how the avro is crated.

Comment: Please file a bug report for Avro -- output is invalid JSON. This regardless of whether there is a work-around to make things work now; others will benefit when generator is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the `\u` like this:

```
{
    "description": "... lives\\uMOVE™ OFFERS ", 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a double escape issue.  I was able to get this to parse in python: '{ "description":"... lives\\\\uMOVE™ OFFERS "}'

Answer (score 1):

Basically the input isn't valid json.

The spec on http://www.json.org/ defines how strings should be be encoded. You will have to fix the JSON output from the other application.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does not currently have a configuration feature to allow accepting such input.  (Was it generated with Jackson?)

You could modify the stream parser to handle it.  Follow the stack trace to the method(s) that would need changing.

You could submit a change request at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON for Jackson to be enhanced to provide such a feature, though I'm not sure how popular the request would be, and whether it would ever be implemented.

Comment: It was generated with jacson (it's output of an avro file)

Comment: Jackson should not produce such output; but if it does somehow, that would be a Jackson bug.